# "Gave up waiting for root device." Ubuntu Server 16.04.04 LTS

Tags: server

folks.

I found several questions related to this error but none seemed to match my situation.

I had a server that was running just fine and had been running for many months without issue up until this evening.

Tonight I decided to run an update ("sudo apt-get update" followed by "sudo apt-get upgrade"). Then I rebooted and now I'm getting this error.

I have an mdadm array setup and that seems to  be the issue. Any ideas on how to troubleshoot this thing from the built-in-shell (ash)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To debug, remove the `quiet splash` from the grub.

I think you are missing modules, but removing that line would show you the complete boot log. Try to boot older kernel.